# What do this means?It 's about DWORD variable in c++

Tags: c++, c, windows

The code:

```
BYTE arBytes[4096];

//write to the arBytes,so the arBytes already not null,then read continue

DWORD* pdw;

pdw=(DWORD*)&arBytes[0];         

if(pdw[0]==dwValue)             //here is what I what to ask
//some operate
}
```

My problem is: what does `pdw[0]` mean? It is a `DWORD*` variable, and `dwValue` is a `DWORD` value too. And it would be better if you indicate the meaning of the code.

Comment: `pdw[0]` is the same as `*pdw`.

Comment: First element of a DWORD array. The byte array is casted in an array of DWORD..

Comment: You have some terminology issues there, which possibly indicate you don't fully understand what is happening. Which I suppose is why you are asking in the first place :) For example, `arBytes` is array, and is never `NULL`, only a pointer can be `NULL`. You probably mean to say, `arBytes` is initialized, there.

Comment: @hyde Yes,I mean that arBytes is initialized there.

Comment: Note that your example is causing undefined behavior due to violation of strict aliasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For :

```
type* identifier;
```

Dereferencing can be done in two ways:

- *identifier - pointer method
- identifier[0] - array method

because array style operations are defined for pointers. So :

> `identifier[0]` is the same as `*(identifier+0)` which is indeed
>   `*identifier`

Coming to your question :

`pdw[0]` is nothing but `*pwd` which is a `DWORD value`.

Answer (score 2):

pdw[0] is reinterpreting the first 4 bytes of arBytes as a type DWORD.

Since DWORD and BTYE are not compatible types, the behavior of your example isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say `sizeof(DWORD)=4` and `sizeof(BYTE)=1`.
So `4 BYTEs` = `1 DWORD`

`&arBytes[0]`. This means address of first BYTE in array `arBytes`.

`pdw=(DWORD*)&arBytes[0];`. The typecasting `(DWORD*)` means now you can access the `BYTEs` of `arBytes` in chunks of 4 via `pdw`. That is, now you can access total of `4096/4=1024 DWORDs` via `pdw`. Which also means that, `pdw` is now an array of 1024 `DWORDs`.

`pdw[0]` means accessing the first i.e 0th element of `pwd`.

`if(pdw[0]==dwValue)` simply means that you are comparing `dwValue` with the value which is formed from combining first 4 elements of `arBytes`.

Here **combining** means arranging the `BYTEs` such that it forms a `DWORD`.
Since `1 DWORD` = `4 BYTEs` so lets say `1 DWORD` is forms as follows `[B0][B1][B2][B3]` where `[B0], [B1], [B2] and [B3]` are `BYTEs`.
Similarly `pdw[0]` is a `DWORD` which is a chunk of 4 `BYTES` such that the chunks's leftmost `BYTE` is `arBytes[0]` and rightmost `BYTE` is `arBytes[3]`.